# How to select a specific option by it's value from a select input and assign different functions for each option?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I want to select specific option from a select input and assign different statement for each of the option. For example -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($('#selectPlans option[value=Starter]:selected')) {
            $('#outcome').html('2 USD');
        }
        else if($('#selectPlans option[value=Premium]:selected')) {
            $('#outcome').html('4 USD');
        }
        else if($('#selectPlans option[value=Business]:selected'))    {
            $('#outcome').html('5 USD');
        }
        else {
            $('#outcome').html('');
        }

});
```

```html
<div class="plans">
    <select name="selectPlans" id="selectPlans">
        <option value="Starter">Starter</option>
        <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
    </select>
    <div class="outcome"></div>
</div>
```

In the above codes whenever someone select the option 
1. "Starter" it should show 2 USD in the section with id "outcome" 
2. "Premium" it should show 4 USD in the section with id "outcome" 
3. "Business" it should show 5 USD in the section with id "outcome" 
There is also another way to do this like the following example

```js
$('#selectPlans').change(function(){
            var optionSelected = $('#selectPlans option:selected');
            $('#outcome').html(optionSelected.val());
        });
```

```html
<div class="plans">
    <select name="selectPlans" id="selectPlans">
        <option value="2 USD">Starter</option>
        <option value="4 USD">Premium</option>
        <option value="5 USD">Business</option>
    </select>
    <div class="outcome"></div>
</div>
```

But in this way I cannot select the specific option. So, I need to know how to select a specific option and assign a function to it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of you have a type error: `$('#outcome')` should be `$('.outcome')`

When that is fixed then you can short your code down to this:

```
$('#selectPlans').change(function() {
  $('.outcome').html($('#selectPlans').val());
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('#selectPlans').change(function() {
  $('.outcome').html($('#selectPlans').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plans">
  <select name="selectPlans" id="selectPlans">
    <option value="2 USD">Starter</option>
    <option value="4 USD">Premium</option>
    <option value="5 USD">Business</option>
  </select>
  <div class="outcome"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed it in my system. Please tell me the next process.

Comment: What is not working? have you checked my demo @AnjanTalukdar